# How to make the background color of CSS cover entire browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

How can I make the background color to cover the entire browser screen?

```css
.top{
    background-color:green;
    color: white;
    height:1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div className = "top">
    <Header/>
    <Body />   
</div>
```

I have tried making the height 100%. But it does not work at all. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Just target the `body`, see code below.

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Additionally, if you want to use the `div` you can add `100vh` and `100vw`;

```css
.top {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <Header/>
  <Body/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `background-color` directly to `<html>`:

```css
html, body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: No code snippet?  You can click "Copy snippet to answer" and add a code snippet with your solution, so someone can see it working instantly.  (All the other answers have code snippets, it would make your answer more competitive.)

Comment: @HoldOffHunger: Done! Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 100vh. This will make the html element take up the entire height of the users screen. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

```
.top{
    background-color:green;
    color: white;
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO!  I think there's a problem with your code snippet?  You have CSS inserted into the HTML block, and no HTML?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Sorry, didn't mean to add a snippet, just wanted to add a code block! Just fixed it.

Comment: Sure sure, good deal, looks better.  Snippets are good too, if you wanted to use the "copy snippet to answer" button up above, that way, people can run your solution instantly and see that it works and is right, etc..  It is satisfying to see instantly working code after searching for an answer.

Comment: This is a snippet of React Code. The root page of a website.

Comment: @user275494 : Right, but, basic rules of HTML and CSS still apply.